# Check for the existence of multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a sql change script that checks for the existence of two columns in a table. If these columns do exist, the script will run alter table to add them. An example of how we check for 1 column is below.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ColumnC')
```

So I need this script to check for the existence of ColumnC and ColumnD.

Comment: Just write this script twice.

Comment: Or check `if (select count(1) from COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME in ('ColumnC', 'ColumnD')) = 2)`

Comment: not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You will want to run the query once for each column unless there is absolutely no way that a table could have one of the columns but not the other.  Because if you check for the existence of both columns at once, and only one of them exists, then if you attempt to add both of the columns the ALTER TABLE will raise an exception, since one of the columns already exists.  Either stick with what you have and do it once for each column, or if performance is crucial, write 3 statements... one for both columns at once and then one for each column.  The pseudocode would look something like:

```
If neither column exists
    Alter table...add both columns
else if ColumnA exists and ColumnB does not
    Alter Table...add ColumnB
else if ColumnB exists and ColumnA does not
    Alter Table...add ColumnA
```

something like this will return tables that are missing both columns...

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C 
    WHERE C.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG 
    AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA 
    AND C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME 
    AND C.COLUMN_NAME IN ('Column1', 'Column2'));
```

Be sure to reference TABLES so that you don't accidentally attempt to alter a view.

Answer (score 0):

**It is just an alternative way, not efficient one**

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     WHERE COLUMN_NAME = '<column_name1>' AND TABLE_NAME ='<table_name>')
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
       WHERE COLUMN_NAME = '<column_name2>' AND TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>')
        BEGIN
             // ....
             // ....
        END
GO
```